# MVC3 Session is inconsistent between controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have two controller methods:

```
public string Nothing() 
{
    if (Session["done"] == null) 
    {
        Session["done"] = false;
    }
    while (!bool.Parse(Session["done"].ToString())) 
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    return "done";
}

public string AnotherMethod()
{
    Session["done"] = true;
    return "hello";
}
```

The first method is called and the second method is intended to stop the execution of the first method. However when I watch the variables during debugging The Nothing method never stop executing and the `Session["done"]` value is always `false`, even after calling the other controller method `AnotherMethod()`

Why is this happening and how can I stop the execution of the Nothing method with a variable change in AnotherMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP .NET, each request gets its own copy of session state meaning The `Session` is thread safe.

You will need other way to achieve what you are trying to do, static variable sounds suitable.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx) MSDN article

---

**Example:**

```
public string Nothing() 
{
    FlagClass.Done = false;

    while (!FlagClass.Done) 
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    return "done";
}

public string AnotherMethod()
{
    FlagClass.Done = true;
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: So a session is created per thread? How will I get around this?

Comment: `static variable sounds suitable`. No. Not unless the state variable should be shared between all users.

Comment: @jgauffin. It can be a static `Dictionary<int(user_id), FlagClass>` if it's needed. So every user gets his own context, just like `Session`.

Comment: @gdoron: of course. Just don't assume that the user knows that.

Comment: @jgauffin. Now he knows it... **:=)**